# No visible @interface for 'NSData'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I am trying to write a NSData variable to a file as a string using the following code:

```
 [filehandle writeData:[myData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

And I am getting the error: `No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'dataUsingEncoding:'`

Comment: Have a look at this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428461/convert-nsdata-to-string

Comment: I am sorry I used a terrible code example. I am actually trying to wrtite it to a text file as a string.

Comment: Hint: The first noun of an Objective-C function name is usually the type of object returned by the function.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: And https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: Is myData of type `NSString` or `NSData` cause only NSString has dataUsingEncoding: and not NSData

Comment: (The message is telling you that there is NO SUCH METHOD for NSData.)

Comment: Then why is xcode suggesting that I use it? All of the code examples I've seen online use it.

Comment: I had a string. I had to convert it into NSData to use the filehandler to write it to the file. While writing it to the file I am trying to write it back as a string.

Comment: Just how is Xcode "suggesting" that?  And where is a code example online that uses it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataUsingEncoding:` isn't an NSData method. I think you want to turn the NSData into an NSString and then ask the string for its `dataUsingEncoding:`.

EDIT: You indicate in your comments that this data was derived from an existing NSString. In that case, just get the data with `[yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and then you can just `[filehandle writeData:myData]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a method which is implemented by `NSString` on an `NSData` object which does not know the `dataUsingEncoding:` method.