# How to open a file in binary form in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and I'm not sure how I can pick up a file and store it in a binary array.

I do know how to pick up a file, but I don't know how I can store it in a binary array which would be modified later.

Suppose the variable "chosenFile" is the file I pick up ( in NSData type)
And the variable "bArray" ( [int8] array) is the array used to store the binary representation of the file.

```
var bArray: [Int8] = [Int8]()
var chosenFile: NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: "xxxxxxxx")
```

Any help ?

Comment: `NSMutableData` would probably be a better place to start than using a `[Int8]`.  If you do want to use primitives (for some reason), surely you want `[UInt8]`?

Comment: Well... What i wanna do is to get the binary representation of a file (lets say an image) and i will modify some of its data to create a new file (image). So in this case should i use UInt8 instead of Int8? Thank you~

Comment: By the way, if altering an image, simply getting `NSData` representation of the PNG or JPEG is generally not very useful. You usually want to get a `CGDataProvider` of the `CGImage`, which is a pixel buffer that is more easily manipulated than trying to parse JPEG/PNG files yourself. See [QA1509](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1509/_index.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an instance of `NSMutableData`, you can use the [`mutableBytes` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableData/mutableBytes) to get a reference to the underlying data.  In C, this would be a `void *`; in Swift, it is an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`.

You can then work with this data directly (there's no need for another byte array).  So long as you stay within the `length` of the `NSMutableData`, you can, eg, [replace individual bits of data, or indeed the entirety of the data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingMutableData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002150).

Alternatively, rather than working on the primitive directly, you can use `replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:` to selectively modify part of your data.  This is also explained in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableData/replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:).

Comment: Thanks~ can i use .getBytes function instead of .mutableBytes? Im now trying to pass this byte array (or mutable pointer) to a C function and then do the modification... Or can i get the byte array from that pointer?

Comment: @Yoope If the C function is going to mutate the underlying data, you'll want to use `mutableBytes`.  You should be able to pass in the resulting `void *` directly to a C function which expects an array (although make sure it knows about the correct size, so that it doesn't try to read/write out of bounds).

Comment: Oh actually the data (raw) would be sent to a server (http) which will process it and send back the result. Can i print the binary data out using this pointer because it now gives me just null if i try to print the raw data out...

Comment: If you're looking to send it online you probably want [to encode it into a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428461/convert-nsdata-to-string), but that's straying into a different question.  You can do whatever you like with the underlying data (although attempting to print it doesn't make a great deal of sense: print it as *what*?)

Comment: I dont need to encode it since the server will deal with the raw data (binary)... Oh it indeed doesnt make sense to print the raw data out but i just wanna check if it is what i need... I guess i would expect it to print out lots of numbers?